# zoom an image on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code for an image that if you tap on it zooms out and if you tap on any where out side the box of the image it zooms back. is there I can control the zooming with a button such that one button zooms incrementally and the other zooms in decrementally. this is my attempt

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head> 
  <style type="text/css">
    .zoomin img { height: 200px; width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease; }
    .zoomin img:hover { width: 300px; height: 300px; } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="zoomin"> 
     <img src="download.jpg" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " /> 
  </div>
</body>
</html> 
<button>plus</button>
<button>minus</button>
```

what better way could this be achieved

Comment: It looks like your code works. What are you trying to change?

Comment: I want if I click the plus button let it zoom out and if you click the minus button let it zoom in

Comment: do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/7/

Comment: where did u set the image

Comment: Don't use `:hover` in this case, but rather `:focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change dimensions of image using `.style.[width/height]`, css will do the rest:

```js
function resize(direction) {
  var delta = 100 * direction;

  var element = document.getElementById('img');
  var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  element.style.width = positionInfo.width+delta+'px';
  element.style.height = positionInfo.height+delta+'px';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head> 
  <style type="text/css">
    .zoomin img { height: 200px; width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease; }
    .zoomin img:hover { width: 300px; height: 300px; } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="zoomin"> 
     <img src="download.jpg" id="img" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " /> 
  </div>
</body>
</html> 
<button onClick="resize(1)">plus</button>
<button onClick="resize(-1)">minus</button>
```

Comment: can it zoom out gradually by tapping on it incrementally and zoom in by tapping on it decrementally that is the plus and minus button. ur answer is cool

Answer (score 0):

This works, I've given each button a class, one plus and one minus, and have addClass and removeClass. An even easier way would be to have one button and use toggleClass to add and remove the class you already have for zoomin.

```js
$('button.zoomPlus').click(function(){
  $('.zoomin img').addClass('zoomer');
});

$('button.zoomMinus').click(function(){
  $('.zoomin img').removeClass('zoomer');
});
```

```css
.zoomin img { height: 200px; width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease; }
    .zoomin img:hover,
    img.zoomer{ width: 300px; height: 300px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="zoomin"> 
     <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " /> 
  </div>
</body>
</html> 
<button class="zoomPlus">plus</button>
<button class="zoomMinus">minus</button>
```