# Increment and decrement image width on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image with two buttons next to it. I want to Increment and decrement 1px when clicking the buttons

```html
<button class="zoom-in">+</button>
<button class="zoom-out">-</button>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature" alt="">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zoom an image on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202705/zoom-an-image-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

This is Your Solution

```js
function zoomin() {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("map");
  var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
  if (currWidth == 2500) return false;
  else {
    myImg.style.width = (currWidth + 100) + "px";
  }
}

function zoomout() {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("map");
  var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
  if (currWidth == 100) return false;
  else {
    myImg.style.width = (currWidth - 100) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
*body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #099;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.main img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/asvd/dragscroll/master/dragscroll.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="navbar">
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomin()"> +</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomout()"> - </button>
  </div>

  <div class="main dragscroll">
    <img id="map" src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature" />
  </div>
```